# How can I get data from Bitfinex authenticated api endpoints using Google sheets?

Tags: api, authentication, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google sheets, I have stored my api_key and api_secret in the Property service section of user info as respectively "api_key" and api_secret".

I want to get wallet info from my account. The code I have written is as follows:

```
function wallet() {
  var api_key = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('api_key');
  var api_secret = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('api_secret');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/auth/r/wallets", api_key, api_secret);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet");
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var wallet_btc = result.BALANCE
}
```

When I run in debug mode the error message is:

```
Cannot find method fetch(string,null,null). (line 13, file "Code")
```

Is this approach wrong, the code wrong, or both?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following modifications?

### Modification points :

- The parameters for `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` are `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)`. And `params` is an object.

  - This is the reason of error `Cannot find method fetch(string,null,null). (line 13, file "Code")`.
- When I saw [the sample scripts for Bitfinex API](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/docs/rest-auth), the request body has to be created using `api_key`, `api_secret`, `nonce`, `body` and `signature`. And `signature` is encrypted by HMAC_SHA_384 and converted to the string of the unsigned hexadecimal.
- The sample for the endpoint of `https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/auth/r/wallets` is as follows. This is from [API reference](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/reference).

#### [Sample](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/reference) for the endpoint of `https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/auth/r/wallets`

```
request.post(
  `${url}/auth/r/wallets`,
  headers: { /* auth headers */ },
  body: {},
  json: true,
  (error, response, body) => console.log(body)
)
```

When above points are reflected to your script, the modified script is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function wallet() {
  var api_key = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('api_key');
  var api_secret = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('api_secret');

  var apiPath = "v2/auth/r/wallets";
  var nonce = Date.now().toString();
  var body = {};
  var rawBody = JSON.stringify(body);
  var signature = "/api/" + apiPath + nonce + rawBody;
  signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_384, signature, api_secret)
    .map(function(e) {
      var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
      return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
    }).join("");
  var url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/" + apiPath;
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      'bfx-nonce': nonce,
      'bfx-apikey': api_key,
      'bfx-signature': signature
    },
    payload: rawBody
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(result)
//  var wallet_btc = result.BALANCE // I couldn't confirm whether this key exists.
}
```

### References :

- [Sample scripts for Bitfinex API](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/docs/rest-auth)
- [API reference](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/reference)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

I cannot confirm whether this works. If this didn't work, can you tell me the situation? I would like to modify.

### Edit :

When you want `0.0957596` from the result of `[["exchange", "USD", 14.81076629, 0, null], ["exchange", "BTC", 0.0957596, 0, null], ["funding", "BTC", 4.13E-6, 0, null], ["funding", "ETH", 3.50186961, 0, null], ["exchange", "OMG", 5.9E-7, 0, null]];`, you can use the following script.

#### Script :

```
function wallet() {
  var api_key = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('api_key');
  var api_secret = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('api_secret');

  var apiPath = "v2/auth/r/wallets";
  var nonce = Date.now().toString();
  var body = {};
  var rawBody = JSON.stringify(body);
  var signature = "/api/" + apiPath + nonce + rawBody;
  signature = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_384, signature, api_secret)
    .map(function(e) {
      var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
      return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
    }).join("");
  var url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/" + apiPath;
  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
      'bfx-nonce': nonce,
      'bfx-apikey': api_key,
      'bfx-signature': signature
    },
    payload: rawBody
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
//  Logger.log(result)
//  var wallet_btc = result.BALANCE // I couldn't confirm whether this key exists.

  var balance = 0;
  for (var i in result) {
    if (result[i][0] == "exchange" && result[i][1] == "BTC") {
      balance = result[i][2];
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(balance)
}
```

#### Note :

- From [the document](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/reference#rest-auth-wallets), it seems that the indexes of `WALLET_TYPE`, `CURRENCY` and `BALANCE` are always `0`, `1` and `2` of each element in the response, respectively.

Comment: brilliant, thank you. The result appears in the log. I will update this when I figure out how to get the bits I need into my spreadsheet. VERY helpful, I am grateful .

Comment: Logs look like this: [17-12-31 08:34:32:093 GMT] [[exchange, USD, 14.81076629, 0, null], [exchange, BTC, 0.0957596, 0, null], [funding, BTC, 4.13E-6, 0, null], [funding, ETH, 3.50186961, 0, null], [exchange, OMG, 5.9E-7, 0, null]]
They seem incomplete. In any case how can I access individual items? 
I tried   var btc = result.exchange.BTC and   var btc = result['exchange']['BTC'] no luck with either.

Comment: @user1903663 At first, from your comment, it is found that the modified script works fine as shown at [here](https://docs.bitfinex.com/v2/reference#rest-auth-wallets). The response is not JSON. It's an 2 dimensional array. So you cannot retrieve the value using ``result.exchange.BTC`` and ``result['exchange']['BTC']``. Can I ask you about the value you want? In your comment, do you want ``0.0957596``?

Comment: @user1903663 Assuming that you want ``0.0957596``, I updated my answer. I added "Edit" to my answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstand your comment, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: you have not misunderstood, it works perfectly. Thank you! However, as mentioned previously, the returned result does not seem to be complete as I have other coins which do not appear to be in the log result. also, I need to iterate through the result and get balances on all coins. I will experiment and update you. Very grateful for this help!

Comment: @user1903663  I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Are the balances on all coins in this data ``[17-12-31 08:34:32:093 GMT] [[exchange, USD, 14.81076629, 0, null], [exchange, BTC, 0.0957596, 0, null], [funding, BTC, 4.13E-6, 0, null], [funding, ETH, 3.50186961, 0, null], [exchange, OMG, 5.9E-7, 0, null]] ``? For the data, you need ``14.81076629, 0.0957596, 4.13E-6, 3.50186961, 5.9E-7``. Is my understanding correct? Can I ask you about the output data you want?

Comment: thanks for your help again. here is the final bit to get what I need: var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
   var balance = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
       balance += result[i][1] + ' ' + result[i][2] + "\n";
       }

Comment: and this puts it into the right cells: for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
         ss.getRange(1 + i, 1).setValue(result[i][1]);
         ss.getRange(1 + i, 2).setValue(result[i][2]);
         ss.getRange(1 + i, 3).setValue(result[i][0]);}

Comment: @user1903663 Thank you for your additional information. I'm glad your problem was solved.